# Show Results Based on experiment_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show

I have a table experiments in my database that is populated by filling out a form. One of the fields in the form is experiment_type, which is a drop down option to select between either AOV or Conversion. In my `show.html.erb` I'd like to display the AOV experiments and the Conversion experiments seperately. I'm kinda stuck on where to begin with this. I thought I could do something in my show action like

```
@aov_experiment = Experiment.where(:experiment_type => "AOV").order("created_at DESC")

@conversion_experiment = Experiment.where(:experiment_type => "Conversion").order("created_at DESC")
```

Then loop through and show the results in my `show.html.erb`

I think I am way off here. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

**Source Code for Displaying Tabs**

```
  <!-- start AOV experiments -->                 




                        <table class="data table table-striped no-margin">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Experiment Name</th>
                              <th>Status</th>
                              <th>Priority</th>
                              <th>Launch Date</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <% @advertiser.experiments.each do |experiments| %>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>

                              <td><%= @advertiser.experiments %></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>

                            </tr>                               
                          </tbody>
                        <% end %>
                        </table>

  <!-- end AOV experiments -->

                      </div>
                      <div></div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content2" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

    <!-- start conversion experiments -->
                          <table class="data table table-striped no-margin">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Experiment Name</th>
                              <th>Status</th>
                              <th>Priority</th>
                              <th>Launch Date</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <!-- begin iteration here -->
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>

                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>

                            </tr>                               
                          </tbody>
                        <!-- end iteration here -->
                        </table>
                <!-- end conversion experiments -->

                      </div>
```

Comment: generally `show` action use to display a single record. why you want to display all records in `show` especially?

Comment: I have an advertisers controller which displays a list of advertisers on the #index, which is my root. When you click the advertiser it goes to the advertisers#show. On this page, I have tabs for AOV Experiments and Conversion Experiments. See screenshot here (http://screencast.com/t/CCgUWnJL9rn)

So basically the idea is to view an advertisers profile page, and inside this page, show a list of AOV and Conversion experiments.

Comment: So basically the view does show a single record. Which is the advertiser. But within the advertiser i want to display a list of experiments separated by experiment_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hard coding in the active record query, you can use something like below,

```
Experiment.all.collect(&:experiment_type).uniq => ["AOV", "Conversion",.....]
```

You can iterate the items from the above array to display tab values. Then you can use ajax to load the content of the tabs. If you find any difficulty ask me...I will tell you how to do that....

But I guess this will give you enough idea.

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: Hi @Andolasoft - Thanks, this help me a lot, but not quite sure how to creating the iteration. I've tried a couple things, but not sure the correct syntax to use. 

I stuck the following in my Advertisers controller under the show action. `@experiments = Experiment.all.collect(&:experiment_type).uniq => ["AOV", "Conversion"]`

In the Advertiser view, having a hard time figuring out the syntax for the iteration.

Comment: Can you give me your source code where you are displaying the tabs.....

Comment: I added the source for displaying tabs above. BTW, the code within that source outputs `#<Experiment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0xbd40b78>` Opposed to any thing that makes sense. Hey, at least I got something to display =)

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? Been trying different things with no luck